# Passing a method pointer for a new method to base class

Tags: c++, vtable

I'd like to be able to call any arbitary method (which are generic methods) defined in a derived class from the base class.  The base class doesn't know about them. I'd somehow like to get this pointer and the virtual table offset and be able to call it.  Class A doesn't actually need to be the base class, it could be a separete class which doesn't know anything about B but needs to call the methods. Is it possible?

```
class A
{
public:
    typedef void (A::*Method)();

    void call(Method p)
    {
        //...
    }
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void meth1()
    {
    }
    virtual void meth2()
    {
    }
    virtual void test()
    {
        call(&TestTask::meth1);
        call(&TestTask::meth2);
    }
};

Errors:
test.cpp:420:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::call(void (TestTask::*)())’
         call(&TestTask::meth1);
                              ^
test.cpp:420:30: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:402:10: note: void A::call(A::Method)
     void call(Method p)
          ^
test.cpp:402:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void (TestTask::*)()’ to ‘A::Method {aka void (A::*)()}’
test.cpp:421:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::call(void (TestTask::*)())’
         call(&TestTask::meth2);
```

Comment: To call B's or any class' methods you need A) An object B) The signature of that function

Comment: What about interface implementation? Derive B from some interface that defines callbacks, and implement it. Class A should know only interface definition.

Comment: Marco, I know the object and signature, how to call?  Alex, interface implies that I know the methods ahead of time--I don't.  Piotr, I can use C++11.

Comment: @YasserAsmi CRTP's solution and interface imply that you know the methods' signatures. Since you do both could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CRTP pattern to accomplish what you are trying.

```
template <typename T> struct A
{
   typedef void (T::*Method)();

   void call(Method m)
   {
      (static_cast<T*>(this)->*m)();
   }
};

struct B : A<B>
{
   void meth1(){}
   void meth2(){}

   void test()
   {
      call(&B::meth1);
      call(&B::meth2);
   }
};
```

Comment: This looks interesting! but I get compiler errors from gcc--error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
    typedef void T::(*Method)();
                    ^
error: ‘Method’ has not been declared
    void call(Method m)
              ^
Member function ‘void B::test()’:
 error: no matching function for call to ‘B::call(void (B::*)())’
       call(&B::meth1);
                     ^
 note: candidate is:
note: void A<T>::call(int) [with T = B]
    void call(Method m)

Comment: @YasserAsmi, I had an error in the `typedef`. It's fixed now. Give in another try.

Comment: @YasserAsmi, you are welcome. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Non-static member functions need an object to act on, so you can't simply call the member-function pointer by itself. You could define a template to call a member of any class, given an object of that class:

```
template <class Class>
void call(Class & c, void (C::*method)()) {
    (c.*method)();
}
```

If that's not what you want, then you'll need to clarify what you do want.